# Instagram: invalid message data error while trying to send pushback buttons

Tags: facebook-messenger, instagram-graph-api, facebook-webhooks, facebook-app-settings

Using https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/me/messages?access_token=pagetoken post url trying to send pushback buttons. But its gives error as:

> ```
> "message": "(#100) Invalid message data",
> "type": "OAuthException",
> "code": 100,
> "error_subcode": 2534015
> ```

```
**Request-body:**
{
"recipient":{
"id":"PSID"
},
   "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"template",
      "payload":{
        "template_type":"button",
        "text":"Try the postback button!",
        "buttons":[
          {
            "type":"postback",
            "title":"Postback Button",
            "payload":"DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is not supported by instagram anymore, try generic type with post back button https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/features/generic-template